# "error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.63"

Tags: package-management, dependencies, libraries

In this specific situation I'm trying to install the latest version of SecureCRT (made by VanDyke).  I get this type of issue every time I update to a new release of Ubuntu.  That said, I've seen this issue with other programs.

Why is this file missing?  Why do we remove the "old" version of the library and/or why do programmers hard code a specific version of shared library?

To date, I do not know how to get around this.  I'd like to understand the deeper reasoning why this keeps happening and how I can fix it when it does happen (if it can even be fixed).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem trying to use Visit software.

I solved the problem using the advise of this tweet: https://twitter.com/sinclairinat0r/status/1237201767198273536

```
wget http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu63_63.2-2_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libicu63_63.2-2_amd64.deb
```

For me it solved the dependency missing.

Comment: Thank you, this worked in Kubuntu 20.04 with SecureCRT 8.7.2

Answer (score 0):

@nurix answer solved the issue to start the application for me, but then I ran into another issue when connecting to a server:

> Could not load libgssapi.so; please ask your sysadmin to create a soft link from your gssapi provider library to libgssapi.so.

If you run into that, you can use this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so
```

You'll need to restart SecureCRT/SecureFX after this