# “error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.63”

Tags: 20.04, package-management, dependencies, libraries

I have downloaded and want to launch qtmips application. When trying to launch it I get this error:

```
./bin/qtmips_gui: error while loading shared libraries: 
libicui18n.so.63: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried getting the library as described in these posts:

- ["error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.63"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239577/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libicui18n-so-63)
- [error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.66:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1351096/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libicui18n-so-66)

but in first, the package is no longer available and I tried to modify the second to

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libicu63
```

to which I only got:

```
unable to locate package.
```

I am fairly new to both Linux and Ubuntu, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `libicu63` is a Debian 10 package https://packages.debian.org/buster/libicu63 → → ↓ https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/libicu63/download